# performance.exe in opencv autoclose when finish

Tags: c++, opencv

i'm new to opencv,i have done the haar-training and get a decent detection. However, when i want to check my hit rate by using performance.exe, it run until finish and auto-close and i cannot check the hit rate, how to solve this? thanks

Comment: did you use the haartraining or the traincascade tool to generate the cascade ? the performance.exe only works with output from the former(old format)

Comment: i use the haartraining to generate the cascade

Comment: is there is any way i cant save the result as this?

[result] (http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#Modified)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are running performance on command prompt; Go to the command line and run:

> C:\Program Files\OpenCV\bin> performance -data TrainingSample.xml -info TestingSample\testsample.txt -sf 1.2 -w 15 -h 20 > TestResult.log

You need to place `TestingSample.txt` in the folder `TestingImages`, if you do not put the `TestingSample.txt` into `TestingImage` then performance program will execute but will not save and show any result. `> TestResult.log` is used to direct the result of execution to log file rather than screen, you can remove it.

Adjust OpenCV path. Please post in details if you see any more problem.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: C:\Users\khairul\Desktop\Haartraining Stuff1\temp\performance.exe -data output.xml -info testing/test.txt -w 24 -h 24 > result.log -ni

i have run this, but the result.log does not created in the testing folder although the performance run until finish.

Comment: result.log should be created in the folder where performance.exe is placed. In your case `C:\Users\khairul\Desktop\Haartraining Stuff1\temp\`  Please check and confirm.

Comment: yes, check in all the folder temp, yet the result.log cannot be found

Comment: Try command prompt, what happens when you run this command. Also try same after removing `> TestResult.log`

Comment: i copy paste the same as i run, C:\Users\khairul\Desktop\Haartraining Stuff1\temp\performance.exe -data output.xml -info testing/test.txt -w 24 -h 24 -ni > result.log
 
but the cmd say the files is not recognized as internal or external command,operable program or batch file